# Inequality of $f(\mathrm{Mode}[X])$ and $\mathrm{Mode}[f(X)]$?

Tags: probability-inequalities, mode

Say I knew the distribution of a continuous variable $X$. If somebody randomly picked out a single instance $x$ and asked me to bet on its value, I would go with the mode of the known distribution of $X$, which is the value that $x$ is most likely to take.

Now consider a function $f(X)$. My immediate intuition would tell me that the most probable value of $f(X)$ would be the one you get from the most probable value of $X$, i.e., that $\mathrm{Mode}[f(X)]=f(\mathrm{Mode}[X])$.

But I can come up with many examples in which this is not the case.
For example, if $X\sim\mathrm{Lognormal}(0,1)$, then $\mathrm{Mode}(X)=e^{-1}\approx0.368$. If $f(X)=e^{-X}$, then $f(\mathrm{Mode}[X])\approx0.692$. We can estimate $f(\mathrm{Mode}[X])$ using simulation:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rlnorm(1e6, 0, 1)
y <- exp(-x)
d_y <- density(y)
mode_y <- d_y$x[which.max(d_y$y)]
mode_y

[1] 0.009808848
```

I am aware of the fact that $\mathrm{E}[f(X)]$ is not generally equal to  $f(\mathrm{E}[X])$ (Jensen's inequality). But $\mathrm{E}(X)$ is not generally the most probable value of $X$.

**Why does the most probable value of $X$ not always produce the most probable value of $f(X)$?**

Comment: Do you know about transformation of measures? It's because of the jacobian term in there. For more details, you might look into the non-invariance of MAP inference, such as in this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330402/what-is-an-example-of-a-transformation-on-a-posterior-distribution-such-that-the

Comment: The mode as estimator of X is an odd choice in the case of a randon variable with probaility density function... It is the MLE, so it makes some sense, but the MLE has good prperties when the sample size is large; we don't consider the MLE for a sample of 1...

Comment: For intuition about one way in which these two modes can come apart, suppose the mode of $X$ is $a$. Let $f$ be a function that maps $a$ to 1, and all other values to 2. Then for practically any distribution $X$ might have, the mode of $f(X)$ will be $2\neq 1 = f(a)$.